# Backing up MongoDB mup deploy

Tags: meteor, kadira

I have successfully deployed my meteor application using [mup deploy](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up/). As stated in documentation to access database we need to run this command:

```
docker exec -it mongodb mongo <appName>
```

How can I use mongodump command with this setup? I have tried running

```
docker exec -it mongodb mongodump --db appName --archive=baza.gz --gzip
```

Command runs successfully, but I can not find baza.gz archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found dump gets saved in docker container. To access backup from local filesystem we need to copy it from docker container.

To dump:

```
docker exec -it mongodb mongodump --db appName --archive=/root/baza.gz --gzip
```

To copy from docker container to local filesystem:

```
docker cp mongodb:/root/backup.gz /home/local_user
```

Comment: The copying does not work like this. The archive does not end up at mongodb:/root/backup.gz. Any ideas?